Configure Storage Account with Sub Modules for each category
I need to create a sub module for each sub resource for Storage Account. I am working on Queue and looking for a way to reference arguments foreach module.
Variable
variable "queues" {
  type = map(object({
    metadata = optional(map(string))
    name     = string
    role_assignments = optional(map(object({
      role_definition_id_or_name             = string
      principal_id                           = string
      description                            = optional(string, null)
      skip_service_principal_aad_check       = optional(bool, false)
      condition                              = optional(string, null)
      condition_version                      = optional(string, null)
      delegated_managed_identity_resource_id = optional(string, null)
    })), {})
    timeouts = optional(object({
      create = optional(string)
      delete = optional(string)
      read   = optional(string)
      update = optional(string)
    }))
  }))
  default     = {}
}

resource "azapi_resource" "queue" {
  for_each = var.queues

  type = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues@2023-01-01"
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      # metadata = each.value.metadata
    }
  })
  name                      = each.value.name
  parent_id                 = "${azurerm_storage_account.this.id}/queueServices/default"
  schema_validation_enabled = false

  dynamic "timeouts" {
    for_each = each.value.timeouts == null ? [] : [each.value.timeouts]
    content {
      create = timeouts.value.create
      delete = timeouts.value.delete
      read   = timeouts.value.read
    }
  }
}

module "storage_queue" {
  source = "./modules/storage_queue"

  for_each = var.queues

  name = each.value.name (
  
}

Error i get when i trying to add name:

Unexpected attribute: An attribute named "name" is not expected here Terraform

During the Validation shows following error
│
│   on ../../main.queues.tf line 8, in module "storage_queue":
│    8:   name = each.value
│
│ An argument named "name" is not expected here. ```



can you please share module "storage_queue" complete info by adding info related to name etc by editing the query so that we have better understanding of the issue @csr1985

updated the module details

module "storage_queue" {
source = "./modules/storage_queue"
for_each = var.queues
name = each.value.name (
}
Is this info provided is complete? or anything missing?

Was the variable name declared as part of the module variables?

@VinayB I just tried adding name there. I got the above error.  I stopped configuring thereafter.

@RuiJarimba . yes

It's hard to help without seeing the whole code and/or the complete error message.

updated the error message as well


Configure Storage Account with Sub Modules for each category using terraform.

To define a sub-module/child-modules using for-each sub-resource and referencing arguments inside a storage account we need to follow the specific sequence while doing so as the parameters are depending on each other.
The general understanding for sub-module we need to start writing the sub-module configuration first and then with following up root configuration. So, during sometimes reversing the sequence may also cause the issue you're facing.
I tried a terraform configuration of your requirement by adding name under module configuration of queue and I was able to overcome the issue and I was able to achieve the requirement successfully using azapi resource for storage queue
Terraform configuration:
main.tf:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "queues" {
  type = map(object({
    metadata = optional(map(string))
    name     = string
    role_assignments = optional(map(object({
      role_definition_id_or_name             = string
      principal_id                           = string
      description                            = optional(string, null)
      skip_service_principal_aad_check       = optional(bool, false)
      condition                              = optional(string, null)
      condition_version                      = optional(string, null)
      delegated_managed_identity_resource_id = optional(string, null)
    })), {})
    timeouts = optional(object({
      create = optional(string)
      delete = optional(string)
      read   = optional(string)
      update = optional(string)
    }))
  }))
  default = {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "sampletestvk-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "exvksbstrageacct"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

module "storage_queue" {
  source             = "./modules/storage_queue"
  for_each           = var.queues
  name               = each.value.name
  metadata           = lookup(each.value, "metadata", {})
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  timeouts           = lookup(each.value, "timeouts", null)
}

module/storage_queue/main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the queue."
  type        = string
}

variable "metadata" {
  description = "Metadata info for the queue."
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

variable "storage_account_id" {
  description = "The ID of the storage account."
  type        = string
}

variable "timeouts" {
  description = "Timeouts of the queue."
  type = object({
    create = optional(string)
    delete = optional(string)
    read   = optional(string)
  })
  default = null
}

resource "azapi_resource" "queue" {
  type = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues@2023-01-01"
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      metadata = var.metadata
    }
  })
  name                      = var.name
  parent_id                 = "${var.storage_account_id}/queueServices/default"
  schema_validation_enabled = false

  dynamic "timeouts" {
    for_each = var.timeouts == null ? [] : [var.timeouts]
    content {
      create = timeouts.value.create
      delete = timeouts.value.delete
      read   = timeouts.value.read
    }
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



Thanks a lot for the feedback. i see you have wrote dedicated variables for "module/storage_queue/main.tf" Can we use same variable block which we used in main.tf in root ?

If we want to create multiple Queues for existing storage account, then we can use this submodule. to achieve this, can we use for_each within the submodule and same variable block we have in root module ? If i use that block, i get the same error.

Since we use "for_each" root module we cannot use it again in the sub-module. we need to pass query details from root module to sub-module @csr1985

Thanks a lot. if we leverage root, how can we create two Queues with existing storage account ?

yes we can create using for_each in the root module to iterate over query definitions which passes the values into submodule which later acts as individual queries @csr1985

I have tried to export queue values, both Queue name and ID as output. But i am getting following error.  Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string). Please can you provide an example on this ?
